# semantics UI Multiple Modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I am new to semantics UI.I have two independent modals on the same page.I am using Semantics UI.However When loading one modal both modals are opening .Any help in this regard is appreciated.

And call to modals is from dynamic generated HTML buttons in a table
Heres the call :
$('#comparewells_modal').modal('show');

Comment: Could  you share the code used for define the modals?

Comment: Here is the HTML code for  modals                                                     
   <div id="comparewells_modal" class="ui small modal large">     MODAL 1 CONTENT                                                              
       </div>                                                                               
 And the second modal HTML :                                                             
          <div id="details_modal" class="ui large modal details">       
        MODAL 2 CONTENT                                                                 
           </div>

Comment: I can not reproduce your error. I tried to reproduce your code and only one modal is open each time. Try to share your code on jsbin o jsfiddle like tihis one http://jsbin.com/qawaxusoqu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks for your response.The code is same as you have written.Only difference is the anchor click functions are inside angularjs controller.

Comment: any solution to this question ?